# Subir imagen a carpeta web en Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto con `Symfony2` y tengo problemas a la hora de subir una imagen a la carpeta web del proyecto.

Con esto obtengo la imagen desde el formulario html:

```
$file = $request->files->get('file');
```

este es el directorio al que la quiero subir:

```
 $ficha='web/imagenes/'.$servicio->getId().'.jpg';
```

con esto supuestamente debe de subir la imagena la carpeta web/imagenes:

```
move_uploaded_file($file,$this->container->getparameter('upload_dir').'/../'.$ficha);
```

este el el parametro en parameters.yml

```
 upload_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads
```

alguna idea?

Comment: Te debe estar quedando algo como `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/web/imagenes/loquesea.jpg`, es la ruta correcta?

Comment: ¿Alguna razón paara usar el parámetro y no usar por ejemplo
 `__DIR__.'/../../web/imagenes/'.$servicio->getId().'.jpg';`  ? Me resulta más efectivo.

Comment: @PaulaAndrea me parece una buena razón el hecho de que si cambia la ruta de subida de imágenes, solo hay que cambiarla en el fichero de definición de parámetros y no en cada lugar donde se haya usado este.

Comment: Puedes colocar el Type de tu proyecto tambíen como estas definiendo en el controlador la subida de archivo. Aca esta la documentación de Symfony https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller/upload_file.html